# removing rows from an array if first entry in row is particular string

Tags: python, arrays

I want to remove all the rows from an array y which have 'copy' as their first entry

I tried this

```
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    if y[i][0] == 'copy':
        n.delete(y,i,0)
```

I don't get an error but the rows haven't been deleted when I print y.

I also tried

```
y[y[:,0] != 'copy']
```

but get the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b03bdf03aa31> in <module>()
----> 1 y[y[:,0] != 'copy']

IndexError: too many indices
```

If anyone could explain why this is not working and suggest a solution it would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: "which have 'copy' as their first entry" what does it mean that it is *their* first entry? Is it a list of lists? Is it a list of strings?

Comment: By first entry I meant the entry in the first column of the particular row I want to delete. The data has a string in the first column then 3 floats in the next 3. It consists of 4 columns in total. I thought I was working with an array but may have misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

With a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
[x for x in y if x[0] != 'copy']
```

With [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and a lambda:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'copy', y))
```